# How to exit the sightless pit in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was at level 7 when I entered the bottomless pit by the time I reached the temple of xirb I hit 9. The falmer and his weird crustacean slaughter me in the temple; there's no way out of the pit (that I can see). How do I get out?

Comment: I TCL'd my way out. A cowards way but the only thing that seemed to work.

Comment: Just be careful of any cave that has words regarding vision.  In this case "Sightless".  All of these are Falmer pits and have a one-way fall.  Actually, just avoid one-way falls in general unless you're ready for them.

Answer (score 22):

You can try the following (non-cheating) methods:

- Save often!
- Lower the difficulty to Novice (restore when you get out)
- Use wards as protection (as pointed out by JAD, watch out for mana cost)
- You can try to just run it till the exit
- Try stealth, or use sneak to lure enemies away one by one and rely on your magicka for healing and perhaps muffle.
- Grind mode: Keep training some magicka skill (illusion might work) until you are able to level up. Don't do so yet! Run toward the exit and level up just before you die, you will get full health when you do so. When you level up pick either Stamina (to sprint longer) or Magicka (to heal more), you could pick health but that won't help if you get surrounded.
- Be very selective with potions and make sure you use them only when in dire need. Magicka, health and stamina will automatically regenerate, but potions won't for obvious reasons.

This is a notorious pit where things start to get a bit more easy around level 15-20.

Comment: Wards are a complete and utter waste of magicka, which would be better spent using healing spells.

Comment: @JAD depends, if the Chaurus spit their poison, a ward may actually be more helpfull than the healing spell. Wards shouldn't be seen as the almight spell that protects everything, but should be efficiently used in perspective of the context of course. Same goes for healing spells, don't heal when at 60% of health, etc...

Comment: Important thing to keep in mind is that a lesser ward costs almost 3 times as much magicka as healing, takes time to be fully effective, falls when taking too much damage. It costs 34 magicka per second. A level 7 character isn't going to be able to keep that up for more than a few seconds.

Comment: True, it is not the most efficient strategy. Perhaps OP could train Restoration to reduce mana cost. :) But then again, it would probably be better to use healing.

Answer (score 10):

Some race-dependent methods:

- Altmer can equip Healing, cast Highborn, then continuously heal while running for the exit.  However, the starter healing spell may be insufficiently powerful without a restoration potion to magnify it (try using both hands, or dual casting if you have the perk).
- Argonians can cast Histskin.  Depending on equipment and level, that may be sufficient to render this fight winnable, or you can run for the exit if it seems unworkable.
- I'm uncertain whether the Imperial's Voice of the Emperor will affect the Falmer.  It certainly will not work on the Chaurus.
- Nords can cast Battle Cry and walk out.  Will affect followers.
- Orcs can cast Berserker Rage and either win the fight or run for the exit.
- Redguards can cast Adrenaline Rush and continuously sprint to the exit (sprinting is significantly faster than running and most enemies will be unable to catch up).

Other context-dependent options:

- Shouts such as Become Ethereal, Slow Time, and (possibly) Unrelenting Force may give you enough breathing room to run for the exit.  Requires completing part of the main quest.
- Illusion spells (probably insufficiently powerful at level 7).
- Invisibility potions.  The Falmer are already blind, but Chaurus are not, so this does still help.
- Fortify sneak enchantments or potions.
- Muffle enchantments or the spell (probably unavailable at level 7).

Comment: Shouts at level 7? He might have Fus, but that is probably it. I doubt he finished the main quest, he would probably have been a higher level if he would.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid: Although defeating the frost troll on the way to the Greybeards is very hard at level 7, running past it is not.

Comment: but doesn't let you level up either. Plus there are dragons involved (one of them is black :)), it would be unlikely he cowared behind a stone and let the followers to all the work. Good answer though!

Comment: @Mixxiphoid: That's why Skyrim is an open world game and allows you to do things like that.  Regardless, once Dragon Rising is complete, it is quite possible to ignore the main quest and start collecting shouts (besides Unrelenting Force).

Comment: I do have fus roh da

Comment: @AvnishKabaj well, what are the odds :). That would have helped you significantly!

Comment: @Mixxiphoid I feel like I don't know how to maximize that shout's potential. I only use it at the starting of the battle when the melee fighters draw in close to me.

Comment: @AvnishKabaj you could have lured them into a group and them use the full shout, that would have knocked (most) of them over, giving you time to escape and hide out of sight again.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid Will keep that in mind for future battles. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

As @Nelson commented, this is an "one-way" cave: you cannot exit the way you came in.

In the *Temple of Xrib* zone, towards the east, there is a tower with a lift to another zone, *Abandoned Cave*. As the name suggests, it should be essentially unoccupied. From there you'll also find an exit.